# No sale para ¨import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;¨

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Al abrir un proyecto nuevo me salen varios errores que se solucionan quitando las dependencias y luego me sale esto que no me importa

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También existen otros errores que no puedo solucionar y no de que van.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar tu archivo build.gradle por favor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema se genera en los recursos, revisa los mensajes, puede ser que tus dependencias especificadas dentro del `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

}
```

no tengan la misma versión que el `compileSdkVersion` especificada.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    ...
    }
```

- Otro factor **importante es asegurar tengas instalado el o los SDK que son indicados en tu `build.gradle`**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta con la versión `compileSdkVersion` y había borrado las dependencias

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

}
```